# Atraso ou não envio dos dados para o back-end, o que fazer?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, react, typescript

Estou com um front-end pronto de um formulário de cadastro, porém eles ta funcionando da seguinte forma: Faço todo o cadastro e ao clickar no botão ele chama a função que pega os valores dos campos e ste em uma variável de estado com os respectivos nomes. Depois disso faço a conexão com o back-end através do axios, enviando um post com os dados para cadastrar. Agora vem erro, eu clicko no botão e nao envia a primeira vez, so está indo na segunda vez que clicko e as vezes somente no terceiro, ou seja, não vai de primeira. Já olhei o back e ele me parece certo, se precisar olhar o código eu também posso mandar. OBS: a senha estou setando em outro lugar.

Código do front:

```js
  const [Senha, setSenha] = useState("")
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [CNPJ, setCNPJ] = useState("")
  const [Nome, setNome] = useState("")
  const [Cidade, setCidade] = useState("")
  const [Estado, setEstado] = useState("")
  const [Endereco, setEndereco] = useState("")
  async function Registrar(value){
    setEmail(document.getElementById("Email").value)
    setCNPJ(document.getElementById("CNPJ").value)
    setNome(document.getElementById("Nome").value)
    setEndereco(document.getElementById("Endereco").value)
    setCidade(document.getElementById("Cidade").value)
    setEstado(document.getElementById("Estado").value)
    if((Senha != "") && (Email != "") && (Cidade != "") && (Estado != "") && (Nome != "") && (CNPJ != "") && (Endereco != "")){
        await api.post("/Cadastro",{
            nomeCondominio: Nome,
            cnpj: CNPJ,
            endereco: Endereco,
            Cidade: Cidade,
            Email: Email,
            Estado: Estado,
            Senha: Senha
        })
    }
  }
```

função que recebe os dados:

```
export const saveCondominio = async (request: Request, response: Response) =>{
    console.log("Salvando os dados...")
    console.log(request.body)
    const con = await getRepository(condominio).save(request.body)
    response.json(con)
}
```

Posso estar passando do jeito errado? ou capturando os dados dos inputs do jeito errado tbm?

Comment: programando errado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `React` o conceito de estado é um dos mais importante, a maneira que tu está utilizando não é a maneira que o `React` faz para recuperar estado de por exemplos de `<input />`.

O código básico para recuperar informações de um caixa de texto é o seguinte:

```
const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

<input type="text" value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
```

criando no caso um variável de estado com o nome de `text` e seu respectivo código para alterar o seu estado o método `setText` e no evento `onChange` a atribuição das informações digitadas na caixa de texto, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');  
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <p>{text || "nada digitado"}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Quando for passar as informações para o seu back-end é só atribuir o valor da variável `text` ou aquela criadas no código. Também tome cuidado com o estilo de programação as variáveis devem começar sempre em minúsculos e as outras partes principal a sua inicial em maiusculos, exemplo:

```
nomePessoa
nome
idadeAluno
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu comecei agora e nao sabia que estava usando errado, voce me ajudou muito.